# Apps script onedit triggered too fast causing code conflicting with itself

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make an applet in Google Spreadsheets and Apps script that scrapes view data about youtube videos searched by users. When a user types in a search query, a new sheet should be copied from a template sheet and customized to the query. The problem I'm encountering is that when a user rapidly types in multiple queries in succession, the script would dump multiple copies of the template sheet and name them 'Copy of template 1', 'Copy of template 2' and so on, whereas the name of each sheet should be "KW: " + its associated keyword. I suspect this is because the function duplicates and renames a sheet, but if two or more instances of a function try this at nearly the same time, they target the same sheet, causing errors.

This is the culmination of what I've tried:

```
function main(e){
  //spreadsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() at the top of the function
  //keyword=the string the user typed in
  //...
  while(true){
    var random=Math.random().toString();
    try{
      //assign the template sheet a random name other processes will fail when they try to use it
      spreadsheet.getSheetByName('template').setName(random);
      //make a copy of the template
      spreadsheet.getSheetByName(random).copyTo(spreadsheet);
      //give the copy a proper name
      spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy of '+random).setName("KW: "+keyword);
      //reset the name of the template so other processes can use it
      spreadsheet.getSheetByName(random).setName('template');
      break;
    }
    //when a process fails, it should wait then try again
    catch(e){Utilities.sleep(Math.round(random*250));}
  //...
}
```

main is has a trigger set on edit. The above code prevents any 'Copy of template n' sheets from appearing, but it simply leaves out most of the sheets that should be produced. My guess is that the code encounters an error in the first line of the try block and loops until it times out. I'm very much at a loss as to what to do. I'd appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the template sheet first, then changing the name of the new sheet. Your solution runs into errors because you're modifying the template sheet, but you should *really* avoid doing that. With this approach, you'll never modify the template sheet.

```
function main(e){
  //spreadsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() at the top of the function
  //keyword=the string the user typed in
  //...
  while(true){ 
    try{
      // Select the template sheet
      var templateSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("template");
      // Set the new sheet name
      var sheetName = "KW: "+keyword;
      // Copy the template sheet and set name
      var newSheet = templateSheet.copyTo(spreadsheet).setName(sheetName);
      break;
    }
    //when a process fails, it should wait then try again
    catch(e){Utilities.sleep(Math.round(random*250));}
    //...
  }
}
```

Granted that I don't have full knowledge of what you're doing with your script, I do have some major concerns with your approach. I don't think you should be creating a new sheet for every query. For one, that will make your data really challenging to aggregate. Secondly, since sheet names must be unique, any time someone searches for something that already has an existing sheet, your function will get stuck in the infinite `while` loop you set up.

I don't know what kind of data you're placing in the sheets, but you should consider trying to record the data in one sheet. Also, although your `while` loop works and will, in the case of errors, eventually be terminated by [Google's script limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations), you should really try (1) implementing something more robust like appending a number to the sheet name and (2) properly [logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging) the errors.

Comment: You wrote templateSheet.copyTo(newSheet); on line 15, but .copyTo takes a spreadsheet as an argument rather than a sheet. I tried the line and the script just halts at that point :/ I could programmatically format the new sheet rather than copying from a template, but that'll be arduous to code. Do you know of an easier way to do it?

Comment: @GuyMichealy Sorry, meant to select & copy the ranges. Please try the revised script and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I tried it without the while loop and try-catch, it inserts more sheets correctly than the previous code, but sadly not all of them. It also doesn't format the sheet correctly because it's only copying the data, so I might as well just create a new sheet step by step programmatically if I'm already doing programmatic formatting. If I include the while loop and try-catch, the code that comes after doesn't run, probably stuck getting an error in the try catch. here's the code if you want to play around with it: https://pastebin.com/3WL9dXi3

Comment: @GuyMichealy The updated code might keep your formatting. For your try-catch statement, check out [the finally clause](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#The_finally_clause).

Comment: I tried the code and it definitely looks like it should perform under pressure, but it doesn't. Do you think the root of the problem stems from Apps Script's ability to handle multiple instances of a function at once?

Comment: @GuyMichealy You should try logging the errors and seeing why a sheet isn't created.